# Convert Trianglemesh to FXyz PolygonMesh Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxyz3d

I'm using the FXyz library to import models (obj format) into my program as Trianglemeshes. I would like to convert these Trianglemesh objects into PolygonMeshes so that they may be used as SkinningMeshes. Is there a specific workflow for this process?

EDIT: I'm using org.fxyz3d.importers.obj.ObjImporter as my OBJ loader. I'm creating and exporting my models in Blender 2.65. Blender 2.65 uses Wavefront as the format.

I had originally tried loading the models in a ThreeJS format, using the HandImporter method, but it was giving me unexpected results. However, the OBJImporter seems to be working perfectly. I figured that if I can load obj models and display them, then I could as a last resort manually attach bones to them and animate them.

Because the PolygonMesh doesn't use a Trianglemesh in any of its constructors, I'm assuming something under the hood is happening which may require some conversions to take place beforehand.

Here's a snippit of my code that I'm using:

```
    private void Load_Model3D(int i) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        
        
        String S = "data\\models\\" + i + "\\" + i + ".obj";
        File F = new File(S);
        if(F.exists()){
         
            
            //Load the Model:
            URL url = F.toURI().toURL();
            this.Model_3D_Arr[i] = FXYZ_Loader.load(url);
            
            //Grab the Trianglemesh from the Model3D using casting:
            MeshView mv = (MeshView) this.Model_3D_Arr[i].getMeshViews().get(0);
            TriangleMesh T = (TriangleMesh) mv.getMesh();
            
            //Convert Trianglemesh into PolygonMesh here:
            
            
        }else{
            
            System.err.println("File F does not exist! FXYZ: " + S);
            
        }
        
    }
```

Thanks again. :)

Comment: Can you edit your question and post how do you import the files and what is the format of your obj file?

Comment: Did you try `Importer3D::loadAsPoly`? See https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Importers/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/importers/Importer3D.java#L79.

Comment: java naming conventions, please ...

Comment: I'll try the loadAsPoly method. Looks like it was just what I needed: Thanks!